# How do I set a place placeholder value for in a text box when using FabricJS?

Tags: fabricjs

I would like to create a text box with a place holder value, simliar to how placeholders [1] work in HTML.

Notably I would like:

1. Some prompt text.
2. The iternal serialized representation to not have the default text.
3. If a user clicks the text area, the prompt text goes away during editing.
4. If the user clicks out of the text area without entering any text, the prompt text comes back.
5. If the user enters text in the text area, the prompt text goes away and also the internal representation changes to have the newly input text.

What would be the cleanest way to do this ?

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefplaceholder